# TextFileConvert - dos2ux and ux2dos in VB.NET

Tags: asynchronous, vb.net, unix

This provides text file conversion capabilities like the common Unix utilities "ux2dos" and "dos2ux".

I needed the capability to perform Unix text file conversions, round trip, within a VB.NET project without being dependant upon external binaries. I couldn't find anything like that on NuGet so I wrote my own.

I'm fairly new to VB.NET and I am self taught. It's for my first original GitHub project! This function works for two text conversion modes currently and I want to get some feedback on my technique here before I complete the project by adding 4 more text conversion modes. It should be able to do conversions between Unix, DOS, and Mac formats. The file should pass an MD5 check if it is converted out and back between any given conversion mode. I want it to run totally Async so it can be used in GUI applications. I hope I am doing the Async stuff correctly...

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class ConvertLineEndings
    ''' <summary>
    '''     These are the different conversions that this library can perform.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Enum TextConvertMode
        Dos2Ux
        Ux2Dos
        'Dos2Mac
        'Mac2Dos
        'Mac2Ux
        'Ux2Mac
    End Enum

    ''' <summary>
    '''     Converts a DOS text file to have Unix line endings.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="originalFile">The file to convert.</param>
    ''' <param name="newFile">The name of a new file to create.</param>
    ''' <returns>Exit code.</returns>
    Public Shared Async Function Dos2Ux(originalFile As String, newFile As String) As Task(Of Integer)
        Return Await ReplaceLineEndings(originalFile, newFile, TextConvertMode.Dos2Ux)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    '''     Converts a DOS text file to have Unix line endings.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="originalFile">The file to convert.</param>
    ''' <param name="newFile">The name of a new file to create.</param>
    ''' <returns>Exit code.</returns>
    Public Shared Async Function Ux2Dos(originalFile As String, newFile As String) As Task(Of Integer)
        Return Await ReplaceLineEndings(originalFile, newFile, TextConvertMode.Ux2Dos)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    '''     Loads a whole text file in to memory, Performs a find\replace, and writes a new file.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="originalFile">The file to convert.</param>
    ''' <param name="newFile">The name of a new file to create.</param>
    ''' <param name="convertMode">This is the type of conversion we are going to perform</param>
    ''' <returns>Exit code.</returns>
    Private Shared Async Function ReplaceLineEndings(originalFile As String, newFile As String,
                                                     convertMode As TextConvertMode) As Task(Of Integer)
        Const cr As Char = ChrW(13)
        Const lf As Char = ChrW(10)

        ' Attempt to detect encoding
        Dim fileEncoding As Encoding = GetEncoding(originalFile)
        If fileEncoding Is Nothing Then Return 4
        Debug.Print(fileEncoding.ToString())

        Dim convertedText As New StringBuilder
        Dim oldFileStream As FileStream = Nothing
        Try
            oldFileStream = New FileStream(originalFile, FileMode.Open)
            Using oldFile As New StreamReader(oldFileStream, fileEncoding, True)
                Do Until oldFile.EndOfStream  ' Read through the whole file
                    Dim readBuffer(0) As Char
                    Dim readChars As Integer = Await oldFile.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, 1)
                    If readChars < 1 Then Exit Do  ' Short circuit 
                    Select Case convertMode
                        Case TextConvertMode.Dos2Ux
                            If readBuffer(0) = cr AndAlso oldFile.Peek() = 10 Then
                                ' Strip out CR chars if followed by LF
                                Await oldFile.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, 1)
                            End If
                        Case TextConvertMode.Ux2Dos
                            If readBuffer(0) = cr AndAlso oldFile.Peek() = 10 Then
                                ReDim Preserve readBuffer(1)
                                ' This is a DOS line ending, keep it.
                                Dim tempBuffer(1) As Char
                                Await oldFile.ReadAsync(tempBuffer, 0, 1)
                                readBuffer(1) = tempBuffer(0)
                            ElseIf readBuffer(0) = lf Then
                                ReDim readBuffer(1)
                                ' Add preceeding CR
                                readBuffer(0) = cr
                                readBuffer(1) = lf
                            End If
                        Case Else
                            Debug.Print("Unimplemented text conversion mode")
                            Return -1
                    End Select

                    convertedText.Append(readBuffer)
                Loop
            End Using

            oldFileStream = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print("Error: " & ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & "Number: " & ex.HResult.ToString)
            Return ex.HResult
        Finally
            If oldFileStream IsNot Nothing Then oldFileStream.Dispose()
        End Try

        'Write the result out to a new file
        Try
            File.WriteAllText(newFile, convertedText.ToString(), New UTF8Encoding(False))
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print("Error: " & ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & "Number: " & ex.HResult.ToString)
            Return ex.HResult
        End Try

        Return 0 ' Exit status 0 is a good thing
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    '''     Attempt to detect the encoding of a file.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="filename">The file to get the encoding pattern from.</param>
    ''' <returns>Encoding type, defaults to ASCII.</returns>
    Public Shared Function GetEncoding(filename As String) As Encoding
        Dim bom = New Byte(3) {}
        Try  ' to read BOM
            Using file = New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                file.Read(bom, 0, 4)
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print("Error: " & ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & "Number: " & ex.HResult.ToString)
            Return Nothing
        End Try

        ' Detect BOM type
        If bom(0) = &H2B AndAlso bom(1) = &H2F AndAlso bom(2) = &H76 Then Return Encoding.UTF7
        If bom(0) = &HEF AndAlso bom(1) = &HBB AndAlso bom(2) = &HBF Then Return Encoding.UTF8
        If bom(0) = &HFF AndAlso bom(1) = &HFE Then Return Encoding.Unicode
        If bom(0) = &HFE AndAlso bom(1) = &HFF Then Return Encoding.BigEndianUnicode
        If bom(0) = 0 AndAlso bom(1) = 0 AndAlso bom(2) = &HFE AndAlso bom(3) = &HFF Then Return Encoding.UTF32

        ' Default to
        Return Encoding.ASCII
    End Function
End Class
```